# The set of all b of $\mathrm{R}^2$ such that the system Ax = b is consistent, is a subspace of $\mathrm{R}^2$ , A is a fixed invertible 2x2 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The set of all b of $\mathrm{R}^2$  such that the system Ax = b is consistent, is a subspace of $\mathrm{R}^2$ , where A is a fixed invertible 2x2 matrix. True or false

## \begin{pmatrix}
 a&  b&  b1\\
 c&  d&  b2
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
 a&  b&  b1\\
 0&  d - \frac{cb}{a}&  b2-\frac{cb1}{a}
\end{pmatrix}

Since it is an invertible matrix, i believe a cannot be zero, and therefore this set of b  $ \ b2-\frac{cb1}{a}$ and $b1$ is the solution set of a homogeneous linear system including the zero set is valid and therefore the set of b is a subspan ? so statement is true

Is my line of reasoning right here?

Comment: Stop and think. If $A$ is invertible, when/how can you solve $Ax=b$?

Comment: It's not correct that $a$ can't be $0$.  What's correct is that if $a=0,$ then both $b$ and $c$ must be non-zero.  But assuming $a \neq 0$ your calculations appear correct.

Comment: oh yea that's true, i missed that case, but does it still change the fact that the set of b's is still a subspan of R^2

Comment: Let me expand on the hint of @TedShifrin:  If $A$ is invertible, then by definition of invertible, what matrix do you know definitely exists?  How can you effectively use that new matrix with the equation $Ax=b$?

Comment: Is it $x=Ab^-1$ already exist, wouldnt i get $AA^-1b = b$
Case a is not zero then 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a&  b&  b1\\
 c&  d&  b2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 c&  d&  b2\\
 0&  b&  b1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then it means that my b1 = b and therefore doesnt contain the zero vector
hence statement is false?

Comment: ^^ i mean when a is zero

Comment: @Baconpancake002 Why do you use $b$ in two different senses, both as a $\mathbb R$ and a $\mathbb R^2$? What does the $b^-1$ in your $x=Ab^-1$ mean?

Comment: maybe i can change the b in my matrix to e,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a&  e&  b1\\
 c&  d&  b2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 c&  d&  b2\\
 0&  e&  b1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so the b i meant in $x=Ab^-1$ is the $\mathrm{R}^2$

Comment: The set of all those $b$ always contains $\pmatrix{0\\0}$ regardless of what $A$ is, because  $$Ax = \pmatrix{0\\0}$$ always has $x=\pmatrix{0\\0}$ as a solution.

Comment: so i believe the statement is true in that case isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible. the system is always consistent, so the set of all $\mathbf b$ such that the system is consistent is just $\mathbb R^2$ itself, which is certainly a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.